# ASP.NET Core 2 not reading endpoints from appsettings

Tags: kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to use ASP.NET Core 2.0's new way of configuring Kestrel endpoints via settings in appsettings.json. This was demonstrated at the Microsoft Build 2017 event (see it on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9hlN0DOKRM&t=1442s) timeframe 21:00-26:20).

The speaker said (and demonstrated) that the following would configuring the listening ports on Kestrel:

```
{
   "Message": "TEST!!",
   "Kestrel": {
      "Endpoints": {
         "Localhost": {
            "Address": "127.0.0.1",
            "Port": "5011"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But this hasn't worked for me. When I use 'dotnet run', the default port of 5000 is still being used. I know the appsettings.json file is being loaded, because I can use the Message value elsewhere.

From the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/5a3ce9fd5d3ae7f6cf117d8f203a4242db6baece/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs), I can't see any place where Kestrel is being configured.

Has anyone else been able to get this method to work? I can't understand how it works in the demo but not in my own code.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was asked a while ago, but I think it would make sense to post on this one as the ASP.NET Core framework has been enhanced to support Kestrel endpoint configuration from application settings since this question was initially asked.
Please find below more details and a little summary on how to achieve that in ASP.NET Core 2.1 and earlier versions.

It is possible to configure Kestrel endpoints in application settings starting from ASP.NET Core version 2.1, as also stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x).

For further details, it is possible to check in the actual [WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/622bdeec84fe502e441f296a9af10bc896848167/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L165) implementation:
from release 2.1, it loads the `Kestrel` configuration section, while on ASP.NET Core earlier versions it is necessary to explicitly call `UseKestrel()` when setting up your `WebHost`.

**ASP.NET Core 2.1 setup**

On ASP.NET Core 2.1, you can setup Kestrel to listen at `http://127.0.0.1:5011` by simply providing the following `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://127.0.0.1:5011" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note you will need to use `Url` instead of `Address` and `Port`.

**ASP.NET Core 2.0 setup**

On ASP.NET Core 2.0 this very same behavior can be achieved by explicitly calling `UseKestrel()` in `Program.cs`. You may use an extension method to keep your `Program.cs` clean:

```
public class Program {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {

        // configuration
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        // service creation
        var webHost = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrelEndpoints(config) // extension method to keep things clean
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();

        webHost.Run();

    }

}
```

The `UseKestrelEndpoints()` is an extension method that looks into the actual configuration settings and setup Kestrel options accordingly:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder UseKestrelEndpoints(this IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder, IConfiguration configuration) {

        var endpointSection = configuration.GetSection("kestrel:endpoints");

        if (endpointSection.Exists()) {

            webHostBuilder.UseKestrel(options => {

                // retrieve url
                var httpUrl = endpointSection.GetValue<string>("http:url", null);

                /* setup options accordingly */

            });

        }

        return webHostBuilder;

    }
```

If needed, you may [setup HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) in a similar way.

Comment: Tested this approach with dotnet core 3.1 with positive results (approach as described for dotnet core 2.1).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that doesn't work anymore. Check out  [How to use Kestrel in ASP.NET Core apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x) . So it doesn't really work with settings anymore. You can do something like the this in you program.cs. Here's I'm setting things up to use https locally but you get the general idea...

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        IHostingEnvironment env = null;

        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
              .UseStartup<Startup>()
              .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
              {
                  env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

                  config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

                  if (env.IsDevelopment())
                  {
                      var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
                      if (appAssembly != null)
                      {
                          config.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, optional: true);
                      }
                  }

                  config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                  if (args != null)
                  {
                      config.AddCommandLine(args);
                  }
              })
              .UseKestrel(options =>
              {
                  if (env.IsDevelopment())
                  {
                      options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 44321, listenOptions =>
                      {
                          listenOptions.UseHttps("testcert.pfx", "ordinary");
                      });
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
                  }
              })
              .Build();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate that is. The Build video specifically said that is how to do it in 2.0. Your example seems very 1.x-like.

Comment: Perhaps. I came to this solution personally  because I wanted to use HTTPS and that protocol is unambiguously not supported as a configuration URL. While reading through that issue on that github, it appeared that URL parsing for Kestrel configuration was a problem and there were going to be additional changes for 2.1. So, I figure this approach works pretty easily AND supports HTTPS. Also, I was tired of looking at the security warning (using http) in my issues list in visual code. :-)

Comment: That's good enough for me. I tried your solution and it does indeed work. I'd really like to simply use the config file (appsettings) though. I'm glad that that bug is logged and will be addressed.