# Find 2 different FREE ports for 2 kestrel servers

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I need to start 2 Kestrel servers from a Console application. The code below shows how I'm doing it now.

Unfortunately, both servers attempt to start on the same ports `HTTP:5000` and `HTTPS:5001` and only first one is actually started.

I also tried to specify [URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51176220/437393) in `appsettings.json` but it doesn't work as expected and I wouldn't like to hardcode server URLs, because if I restart Console app it doesn't kill previously started servers and can't start them again.

**Question**

How to **find free ports** for HTTP and HTTPS for both servers **from code** and make sure that they are different?

**Server**

```cs
public class WebServer
{
  public static IWebHost Run<TStartup>(WebOptions options = null)
  {
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().Build();

    var environment = WebHost
      .CreateDefaultBuilder(new string[0])
      .ConfigureServices(o => o.AddSingleton(options))
      .UseConfiguration(configuration)
      .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .UseKestrel()
      .UseStartup<TStartup>()
      .Build();

    environment.RunAsync();

    return environment;
  }
}

var serviceEnvironment = Server.Run<ServiceStartup>();
var webEnvironment = Server.Run<WebStartup>();
var serviceAddresses = serviceEnvironment.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>().Addresses;
var webAddresses = webEnvironment.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>().Addresses;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to port 0 and Kestrel will find a random available port automatically.

From the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#port-0) for Kestrel:

> When the port number 0 is specified, Kestrel dynamically binds to an
> available port. The following example shows how to determine which
> port Kestrel actually bound at runtime:
>
> ```cs
> public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
> {
>     var serverAddressesFeature = 
>         app.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();
>
>     app.UseStaticFiles();
>
>     app.Run(async (context) =>
>     {
>         context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
>         await context.Response
>             .WriteAsync("<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head>" +
>                 "<title></title></head><body><p>Hosted by Kestrel</p>");
>
>         if (serverAddressesFeature != null)
>         {
>             await context.Response
>                 .WriteAsync("<p>Listening on the following addresses: " +
>                     string.Join(", ", serverAddressesFeature.Addresses) +
>                     "</p>");
>         }
>
>         await context.Response.WriteAsync("<p>Request URL: " +
>             $"{context.Request.GetDisplayUrl()}<p>");
>     });
> }
> ```